# Not able to Read and Write Objects from file while using Servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I was trying to write objects and retrieve it using Servlets, But I am getting 
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.model.User
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)

Even though I implemented Serializable to the com.example.model.User class.
Could you please correct where I went wrong. Thanks in Advance.

**1) SignUPServlet**

```
package com.example.web;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.example.model.*;


public class SignUpServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException, IOException{
        String userName =  req.getParameter("userName");
        User regUser= new User(userName);
        SaveUser saveUser = new SaveUser();
        saveUser.writeUser(regUser);
        saveUser.store();

        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
        out.println("<h1> User registered </h1>");
    }

}
```

**2)SignInServlet**

```
package com.example.web;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.example.model.*;

public class SignInServlet extends HttpServlet{

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException{

        String userName = req.getParameter("userName");
        HttpSession ses = req.getSession();

        RetrieveUser rUsers= new RetrieveUser();
        User user = rUsers.getUser(userName);
        if(user != null){
            ses.setAttribute("user",user);
            RequestDispatcher view = req.getRequestDispatcher("feeds.jsp");
            view.forward(req,res);

        }
        else{
            PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
            pw.println("<h3> User is not Registered, SignUp please </h3>");
        }


    }


}
```

**3)User**

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String userName;
    private UserPost userPost;
     private List<User> friendList;
     private List<UserPost> myPostList;

    public User(String userName){
        this.userName= userName;
          this.friendList= new ArrayList<User>();
        this.myPostList= new ArrayList<UserPost>();

    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return this.userName;
    }

     public List<User> getFriendList(){
         return this.friendList;
     }

     public List<UserPost> getPosts(){
         return this.myPostList;
     }

     public UserPost getUserPost(){
         return this.userPost;
     }

     public int getTotalPost(){
         return myPostList.size();
     }

     public boolean addFriend(User friend){
         if(friendList.contains(friend)){
             return false;
         }
         friendList.add(friend);
         return true;
     }

     public boolean removeFriend(User friend){
         if(friendList.contains(friend)){
             friendList.remove(friend);
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }

     public void addPost(UserPost uPost){
         this.userPost = uPost;
     }

}
```

**4)UserPost**

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.*;

public class UserPost implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String content;
    private int likes;
    private List<String> comments;

    public UserPost(String content){
        this.content= content;
        this.likes= 0;
        this.comments = new ArrayList();
    }

    public void increaseLikes(){
        likes++;
    }

    public void addComment(String comment){
        comments.add(comment);
    }

    public String getContent(){
        return this.content;
    }

    public int getLikesCount(){
        return this.likes;
    }

    public List<String> getComments(){
        return this.comments;
    }

}
```

**5)SaveUser**

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import com.example.model.*;

public class SaveUser implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private FileOutputStream fos;
    private ObjectOutputStream out;
    private String filePath;
    private List<User> savingUserList;

    public SaveUser(){

        this.filePath = "/home/baalajisk/tomcat/webapps/MYFaceBook/WEB-INF/tempsavedUsers";
        try {
            this.fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath, true);
            this.out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            this.savingUserList = new ArrayList<User>();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void writeUser(User user){
        try{
            savingUserList.add(user);
            out.writeObject(savingUserList);
            System.out.println("Storing user: "+user.getUserName());

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void store(){
        try{
            out.close();
            fos.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**6)RetrieveUser**

```
package com.example.model;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;



public class RetrieveUser {

    private List<User> retrievedUserList;
    private String userName;
    private String fileName;
    private FileInputStream fin;
    private ObjectInputStream in;

    public RetrieveUser(){

        this.fileName = "/home/baalajisk/tomcat/webapps/MYFaceBook/WEB-INF/tempsavedUsers";
         this.retrievedUserList = new ArrayList<User>();
         try {
             this.fin = new FileInputStream(fileName);

         }
         catch (Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        getSavedUserList();

    }

    private void getSavedUserList(){

        try{

                in=new ObjectInputStream(fin);
                retrievedUserList=(List<User>)in.readObject();

        }
        catch(EOFException eof){

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }
        finally {
            try {
                in.close();
                fin.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



       }
    public User getUser(String UserName){
         for(int i=0;i<retrievedUserList.size();i++){
             User userFromList = retrievedUserList.get(i);
             if(userFromList.getUserName().equals(UserName)){
                 return userFromList;
             }
         }
         return null;

    }

}
```

Catalina.out

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.model.User
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:896)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1145)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
at com.example.model.SaveUser.writeUser(SaveUser.java:33)
at com.example.web.SignUpServlet.doPost(SignUpServlet.java:17)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:543)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:615)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:818)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1627)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: Could you please add the full stack trace

Comment: Yeah I added full stack trace of the exception